# Automation Excel From Python getting "TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable" on Range.Address

Tags: python, excel, com

As per the Title, when I run the below code in Python 2.6 I get the below error on line:

> print range.Address(RowAbsolute=False,
>   ColumnAbsolute=False)"

I know what the error means but the MSDN page ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174749(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174749%28v=office.11%29.aspx)) said this is valid and has an example in it. I have tried this in EXCEL VBA and it works.

> TypeError: 'unicode' object is not
>   callable

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Doanld

```
import win32com.client

xlApp =  win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
xlApp.Visible = True

objWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
objSht = objWkb.Worksheets(1)
objSht.Cells(2,2).Value = '1'
objSht.Cells(2,3).Value = '2'

range = objSht.Cells(2,4)
range.Value = '=%s+%s' % (objSht.Cells(2,2).Address, objSht.Cells(2,3).Address)
range.AddComment('Test Comment')

print range.Address
print range.Address(RowAbsolute=False, ColumnAbsolute=False)

objWkb.Close(SaveChanges=False) #to avoid prompt

xlApp.Quit()
xlApp.Visible = 0 #must make Visible=0 before del self.excelapp or EXCEL.EXE remains in memory.
del xlApp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Range.Address` is a *parameterized property*.  It provides a value when accessed like a property, but can be called like a method with parameters as well.  PyWin32 does not support parameterized properties directly.  It works around this by providing a GetXXXXX method for each property that supports parameters.  Use:

```
range.GetAddress(RowAbsolute=False,ColumnAbsolute=False)
```

It can be used with or without keywords.

Use either:

```
range.GetAddress()
range.Address
```

To read the property.

Comment: +1.  Excellent.  I'm embarrassed about how completely wrong my answer was.